# "Cannot find module" error message with gulp-jasmine

Tags: node.js, typescript, tslint, tsconfig

My ts source files output is in root/distr folder.

My ts test files output is in the same folder as sources: root/tests

I have this directory structure:

```
root
--- distr
   --- fileA.js
   --- api
      --- myapi.js
--- src
   --- fileA.ts
   --- api
       --- myapi.ts
--- tests
    --- unit
        --- specs
            --- api
                --- testA.spec.js
                --- testA.spec.ts
```

`testA.spec.ts` content:

```
import * as myapi from "api/myapi"; //<= this is where I get the error

describe("API: \"app/version\" route", () => {

    it("should return the version", (done) => {
        expect(200).toBe(200); //on purpose for now
        done();
    });
}
```

`tsconfig.json` content:

```
"outDir": "../distr",
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
     "*": ["src/*"],
     "api/*": ["src/api/*"],
},
```

In `gulpfile.js` content, I have:

```
runSequence('clean:tests', 'build:tests', 'jasmine', function() {
    done();
});


gulp.task('build:tests', function () {
    return gulp.src(['tests/**/*.ts'])
      .pipe(ts())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('tests/'));
});

gulp.task('jasmine', function(done) {

    return gulp.src('tests/**/*.spec.js')
        .pipe(plumber(function (error) {
            console.log(error.toString());
            this.emit('end');
        }))
        .pipe(jasmine());
})
```

When I run the gulp command, I get:

```
[19:44:25] Starting 'build:tests'...
[19:44:28] Finished 'build:tests' after 2.39 s
[19:44:28] Starting 'jasmine'...
BLA:Error in plugin "gulp-jasmine"
Message:
    Cannot find module 'api/myapi'
Details:
    code: MODULE_NOT_FOUND
```

Any idea why I get this message?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try:

`import EngineA from "./engines/engineA"`

(make sure the local path is right). If that's it then you must configure `"baseUrl": and "rootDirs" in`tsconfig.json` correctly. Good luck.

Comment: I configured the paths section of tsconfig.ts so that I don't have to use relative path (that would be something like "../../../../src/api/myapi")
It works fine when I build the ts from src folder, not with the tests folder.

Comment: I was wrong about the property names, fixed it. What happen if you just execute jasmine or tsc without gulp ? like `npx tsc && npx jasmine``? if that works gulp is messing up with the structure somehow.. sorry not being of much help - when things broke like that I tend to simplify and go to the basics...

Comment: so I guess your problem is gulp configuration - not in tsconfig.json - are you sure you want to use gulp ? I'm sure you have your reasons and gulp is great, but with just typescript and ts-node depdencies and these two npm scripts you have run and watch experience and I'm sure is faster than with gulp: 
    "test": "ts-node node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine", 
    "watch": "tsc --watch",
and BTW you don't have to worry about sourcemaps to easy debug your tests because you are executing ts code "directly". my two cents, good luck